# Is it possible to find a proper divisor of a composite Fermat Number without using any arithmetic operation +-*/?

Tags: number-theory

I have an absurdly simple algorithm which for N = 2^{2^{k-1}} +1 a composite Fermat Number,
computes a divisor 1

The algorithm is also a test for primality, i.e. N is prime if and only if my algorithm
has output e=N.

Features:

1. The algorithm is a k-step recursion. Hence it contains no steps which involve "Trial & Error".
2. The algorithm involves simple manipulations of bit strings. It uses non of the
   arithmetic operations +,-,*,/.

My goal is to prove that no such algorithm as I have just described is possible. This would be the contradiction in a theorem I proving.

Comment: All of those arithmetic operations can be implemented as simple manipulations of bit strings.

Comment: Proving in general that an algorithm doesn't exist is extremely difficult.  For example, the following question is open: Is there are a linear time algorithm for multiplying two positive integers?

Comment: Sure, arithmetic operations can be implemented as simple manipulations on bit strings. But with my algorithm the point is that none of what I do amounts to performing any arithmetic operations.

Comment: What I am attempting to show is the opposite of finding some optimal algorithm. I seek to prove that all algorithms to find divisors of Fermat Numbers or to prove they are composite requires some minimal operations, namely arithmetic operations.